# When should we use cond_syscall while adding a system call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am reading this link regarding adding a new system call.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/process/adding-syscalls.html

> The file kernel/sys_ni.c provides a fallback stub implementation of
>   each system call, returning -ENOSYS. Add your new system call here
>   too: cond_syscall(sys_xyzzy);

Why do we need this?
For example on x86, i will add my entry point to system call table present in arch/x86

Comment: I am also trying to figure this stub part too. I think this is mostly for systems where the syscalls are not implemented, and user tries to call, wherein it hits the callback. Also this is optional for build.